# Multiple field groups with empty fields

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-fields

I'm trying to make this working

```
 [Title Field] [Link Field]

 [Add More values] // Will add a [Title Field] [Link Field]
```

But for example the first `[Title Field]` is having the value: Foo. With a link to http://foogle.fo
Then I click on `[Add More values]`, and a new row of a group field is showing. In this row I only write in the `[Link Field]`.

When I save this, it will also save the right connection between Title and Link field. But how could I possibly print this in a loop, like this `print_r($node->field_titel);` this will only return one field (that one with a value), I also want the empty one so I could fetch the links connected to each title.

See image for clearer information about the field groups.
[image: An example of multiple field]
So if there would be a third row, the second row would not fetch the second `Beskrivning` value, it will fetch the third `Beskrivning`. Because the object `$node->field_beskrivning` Will not return any empty results.

So, what I want is a `$node->field_beskrivning` with the empty rows in right order or any other examples of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Field Collection module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)

> The Field Collection module is the successor to the CCK3 Multigroup.
>   It allows a set of fields to be combined together and treated as a
>   single field. For example, a field collection named Playlist can be
>   created consisting of the text fields Song and Artist. When a Playlist
>   entry is created the Song and Artist fields are presented together as
>   elements of the Playlist field.